# Postgresql trigger function syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, aggregate-functions

Hi this is my first trigger function on pgAdmin3 postgresql, I tried and have given up, I want to add a trigger to populate the item_sold table if an item has been sold. Im doing an assessment for etrading site.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trPopulateItemSold()
AFTER UPDATE ON tradebay.item FOR EACH ROW    
RETURN trigger AS $populate$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO item_sold (transaction_id, quantity, buyer_id, item_id) VALUES (transaction_id, NEW.quantity, buyer_id, NEW.item_id);
END;
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

SQL error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: CREATE TRIGGER trPopulateItemSold()
                                     ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CREATE TRIGGER` syntax is invalid. You're misunderstanding how it works.

Trigger creation is done in two steps:

- Create the function that implements the trigger logic; then
- Create a trigger that runs the function when something happens

See the PostgreSQL manual for details and examples:

- [PL/PgSQL trigger procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html); and
- [`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

You seem to be trying to mash the two together into a single step. That will not work. You need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION .... RETURNS trigger AS $$
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER ...;
```